# Raster to polyline with only one feature for each unique value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, raster-conversion, polyline-creation

When I convert my raster layer to a polyline layer, the cells that are located very close to each other (even with different values) are connected to each other which is unwanted and very hard to get rid off:
[image]

It seems to me this won't happen if only the cells with the same value were connected to each other to create a feature. How can I do that? I already tried creating points for each cell and then making a polyline layer from them which didn't work because of the random ordering of the created points:

[image]

I've used ArcGIS 10.2.2 for these images but I also use  QGIS, GRASS, and R.

Comment: I have script for this in ArcGIS, it is using external package networkx. Let me know if this is of interest

Comment: @FelixIP yes, if it does the job please do share. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Connects points to make polyline. Makes one line at a time
# Tool assumes that 1st layer in Table of Conternt is TARGET polyline feature class,
# second layer in TOC is SOURCE point fc.
# If no selection found in SOURCE layer, works on entire dataset

import arcpy, traceback, os, sys
import itertools as itt
from math import sqrt
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\felix_pertziger\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages')
import networkx as nx
from networkx import dijkstra_path_length

try:
    def showPyMessage():
        arcpy.AddMessage(str(time.ctime()) + " - " + message)
    def CheckLayerLine(infc):
        d=arcpy.Describe(infc)
        theType=d.shapeType
        if theType!="Polyline":
            arcpy.AddWarning("\nTool designed to work with polylines as TARGET!")
            raise NameError, "Wrong input\n"
        return d
    def CheckLayerPoint(infc):
        d=arcpy.Describe(infc)
        theType=d.shapeType
        if theType!="Point":
            arcpy.AddWarning("\nTool designed to work with points as SOURCE!")
            raise NameError, "Wrong input\n"
        return d
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
    if len(layers)<=1:
        arcpy.AddWarning("\nNot enough layers in the view!")
        raise NameError, "Wrong input\n"
    destLR, sourceLR=layers[0],layers[1]
    a = CheckLayerPoint(sourceLR);d = CheckLayerLine(destLR)

#  copy all points to manageable list
    g=arcpy.Geometry()
    geometryList=arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(sourceLR,g)
    nPoints=len(geometryList)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Computing minimum spanning tree')
    list2connect=[p.firstPoint for p in geometryList]
#  create network    
    p=list(itt.combinations(range(nPoints), 2))
    arcpy.SetProgressor("step", "", 0, len(p),1)
    G=nx.Graph()
    for f,t in p:
        p1=list2connect[f]
        p2=list2connect[t]
        dX=p2.X-p1.X;dY=p2.Y-p1.Y
        lenV=sqrt(dX*dX+dY*dY)
        G.add_edge(f,t,weight=lenV)
        arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()
    arcpy.AddMessage(len(G.edges()))
    mst=nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G)
    del G

#  find remotest pair
    arcpy.AddMessage(len(mst.edges()))
    length0=nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(mst)
    lMax=0
    for f,t in p:
        lCur=length0[f][t]
        if lCur>lMax:
            lMax=lCur
            best=(f,t)
    gL=nx.dijkstra_path(mst,best[0],best[1])
    del mst
    nPoints=len(gL)
    ordArray=arcpy.Array()
    for i in gL: ordArray.add(list2connect[i])

#  append line to TARGET
    curT = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(destLR,"SHAPE@")
    curT.insertRow((arcpy.Polyline(ordArray),))
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    del curT

except:
    message = "\n*** PYTHON ERRORS *** "; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Traceback Info: " + traceback.format_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])[0]; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Error Info: " +  str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"; showPyMessage()
```

NOTE:
If you expect sharp u-turns, split task in parts

Comment: I came to GIS stack exchange after years and I saw this question I had and your response, and I never had thanked you! Please accept my belated thank you (after 6 years   ...)